# The kernel of free group map to surface group

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation

$G$ is a surface group of genus $g\geq 2$ (the fundamental group of closed orientable surface of genus g). $F$ is a free group of rank $2g$ with basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_{2g}\}$. $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism from $F$ to $G$ such that $G$ is generated by $\phi(x_1),\dots,\phi(x_{2g})$.

1. What can we say about the kernel of $\phi$?
2. Is it *always* the normal closure of an element $r$ in $F$?
3. Can we write $r$ explicitly if it is?

Comment: How can you have an endomorphism from $F$ to $G$?  You must mean either "homomorphism" or "epimorphism".

Comment: As an aside, I don't at all understand the votes to close this question.  It seems like a good question to me.

Comment: @JimBelk I mean surjective homomorphism. My english is poor.

Comment: This is an intersting question, possibly more suitable for MathOverflow. So why are there three votes to close?

Comment: A related question: given any two generating sets of $G$ of size $2g$, is there an automorphism of $G$ taking one to the other? If yes, then the answer to 2 is yes, and it also helps with 3.

Comment: @DerekHolt I disagree that this is more suitable for MathOverflow. It is essentially just an application of Seifert-van Kampen (in fact, I just checked and this is the example Wikipedia uses! See also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136331/the-fundamental-group-of-a-closed-surface-without-classification-of-surfaces)). On the other hand, if you interpret 2 as saying "Is it *always* the normal closure of an element $r$..." then things become interesting (I don't think this is the interpretation the OP was going for).

Comment: Interestingly, the alternative interpretation has a positive answer, which is due to a [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0454) of Lars Louder. He proves that the generating tuple $(\phi(x_1), \ldots, \phi(x_{2g})$ is Nielsen equivalent to the "standard" generating tuple $(y_1, \ldots, y_{2g})$, from which this result follows.

Comment: @DerekHolt Also, what you want to happen with automorphisms cannot happen for $g>1$ (but does happen with Nielsen transformations, which is the point). The "correct" formalisation of what you are going for is that "$G$ contains one $T$-system of generating $2g$-tuples". A counter-example to the $g>1$ case is taking $x_1\mapsto x_1x_3$ and $x_i\mapsto x_i$, $i\neq 1$, using the standard presentation. This gives you two generating sets which cannot be obtained one from the other using an automorphism.

Comment: @user1729: Thanks! I did interpret 2 as meaining "is it always...". It seems to me that your comments strongly imply that the question is a lot more suitable for MathOverflow. The vast majority of recent questions on MSE in group theory have been very elementary, and questions like this are in danger of being closed! Several recent questions on group theory on MathOverflow have been much easier than this, but have still attracted large numbers of votes.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah, okay, I haven't really been keeping tabs on MO lately. I have to admit that I really like this interpretation of the question. It would be interesting to see if there was a lower-level proof, rather than using a research paper.

Comment: @user1729 yes, DerekHolt 's interpretion is that I want to ask. I knew the standard presentation of surface group.

Comment: @J.C.Wu: hi, I edited the question to include the word "always" in item 2. Please check to see if this is indeed what you mean. And if there are additional statements from the discussion of user1729 and DerekHolt that you feel will help clarify the question, please feel free to add them into the question statement itself.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I said in the comments above, this has a positive solution due to a recent preprint of Lars Louder, which can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0454). The paper proves that surface groups have a "single Nielsen equivalence class of generating $2g$-tuples". I'll explain what this means, and then I will explain why this solves the problem. (In the comments below, Lars Louder has pointed out that the quoted result is due to Zieschang for genus $g\neq 3$, and that his own results are much more general.)

Let $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ be a generating tuple for a group $G$. Then clearly all permutations of this tuple are generating tuples for $G$, as are $(x_1^{-1}, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(x_1x_2, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. These alterations correspond to *Nielsen transformations*, or equivalently, to automorphisms of the free group $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. Indeed the Nielsen transformations I described above generate all Nielsen transformations, that is, if you repeat the above alterations then you obtain all of the "obvious" generating tuples for $G$, for example if $n=3$ then $(x_1^{-1}, x_2x_1x_3, x_2x_1)$ will be obtained, and so on. If two generating $n$-tuples can be obtained one from the other in this way then they are said to be *Nielsen equivalent*. They partition the generating tuples into *Nielsen equivalence classes*.

Fix $G=\langle y_1, z_1, \ldots, y_g, z_g; [y_1, z_1]\cdots [y_g, z_g]\rangle$. What Lars Louder have proven is that if $\mathcal{L}_1=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{2g})$ generates $G$ (note that each $x_i$ denotes a word over $y_{\ast}$ and $z_{\ast}$) then $\mathcal{L}$ can be obtained from the standard generating tuple $\mathcal{L}_0=(y_1, z_1, \ldots, y_g, z_g)$. It is then an easy exercise to see that when you go from the generating tuple $\mathcal{L}_0$ to $\mathcal{L}_1$ via your Nielsen transformation $\phi$, so $\phi(y_1)=x_1$, $\phi(z_1)=x_2$, etc. you obtain the following presentation of $G$.
$$\langle y_1, z_1, \ldots, y_{g}, z_g; [x_1, x_2]\cdots [x_{2g-1}, x_{2g}]\rangle$$
Recall that each $x_i$ denotes a word over $y_{\ast}$ and $z_{\ast}$, so this presentation makes sense.

There are some old results in a similar vein from the 70s. For example, Steve Pride proved that one-ended two-generator, one-relator groups with torsion have a single Nielsen equivalence class of generating pairs (and this solves the isomorphism problem for such groups), while at around the same time Brunner proved that the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(2, 3)=\langle a, t; t^{-1}a^3t=a^3\rangle$ has infinitely many Nielsen equivalence classes of generating pairs. In fact, Brunner proves something stronger. Two generating tuples $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ of a group $G$ are said to *lie in the same T-system* is there exists an automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ such that $(\phi(x_1), \ldots, \phi(x_n))$ is Nielsen equivalent to $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$. Brunner proves that $BS(2, 3)$ has infinitely many T-systems. (The "T" stands for transitivity, if I recall correctly.)

Comment: Good answer! In Lyndon & Schupp's book "combinatorials group theory" page 93, they stated $BS(2,3)=<a,t;t^{-1}a^2t=a^3>$ has no presentation with two generators $t, a^4$ and only a single relator. Do you know how many T-systems the Fuchsian type group has?

Comment: Lyndon and Schupp's example is -essentially- the first step in Brunner's proof. In fact, if you turn to p96 they briefly discuss Brunner's work. What do you mean by "*the* Fuchsian type group"? (I suspect my answer will be "no, I do not know" though.)

Comment: Thank you let me turn to page 96. I see Ziechang had established the analogous result for Fuchsian type group (line 2).

Comment: Careful though - the analogous result is not saying that these groups have one Nielsen equivalence class. Rather, it is saying that automorphisms of the group when viewed in the given presentation keep the given generating tuple in a fixed Nielsen equivalence class.

Comment: "It is then an easy exercise to see that when you go from the generating tuple L0 to L1 via your Nielsen transformation ϕ, so ϕ(y1)=x1, ϕ(z1)=x2, etc. you obtain the following presentation of G.<y1,z1,…,yg,zg;[x1,x2]⋯[x2g−1,x2g]>"

How to see these?

Comment: @J.C.Wu This follows from the fact that Nielsen transformations are Tietze transformations.

Comment: I don't have any reputation points so I can't comment on user1729's answer, but I'd like to note that, as stated, the theorem he attributes to me is originally due to Zieschang, but only for $g\neq 3$. The theorem I proved is stronger in that there is no restriction on the genus, orientability, or the rank of the free group, provided there is a surjective map $F\to G$, i.e., a generating tuple $(y_1,\dotsc,y_n)$ is equivalent to $(x_1,\dotsc,x_{2g},1,\dotsc,1)$ (in the oriented case).